# Smalltalk - convert string to lowercase

Tags: smalltalk

Is there a way to use `collect:` to help convert a string to lowercase? As in, I'm not allowed to use `translateToLowercase` or `asLowercase`. I don't want the answer, just an idea of where I could look to get me started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collect` as a sort of mapping operation. Here is an example:

```
(1 to: 10) collect: [ :x | x squared ] "=> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]"
```

For your purposes you'd want to use something other than `squared`. This will let you perform the operation one character at a time.

Hope this helps, you said you didn't want the answer.